# how to denied open new window in geckofx?

Tags: c#, geckofx

i can't find way to denied open new window when clicking links on webpage. All preferences about popups is not working.

I want to open any clicked links in current window. How can i do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the event CreateWindow to handle a new popup window:

```
GeckoWebBrowser wb1 = new GeckoWebBrowser();
wb1.CreateWindow += new EventHandler<GeckoCreateWindowEventArgs>(wb1_CreateWindow);
```

Here event CreateWindow:

```
void wb1_CreateWindow(object sender, GeckoCreateWindowEventArgs e)
{
    //Keep popup new window here!
    e.Cancel = true;

    //e.WebBrowser.Navigate(e.Uri);

    // OR

    //GeckoWebBrowser wb1 = new GeckoWebBrowser();
    //wb1.Navigating += new EventHandler<GeckoNavigatingEventArgs>(wb1_Navigating);
    //wb1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    //wb1.CreateControl();
    //TabPage tab1 = new TabPage("New WebBrowser");
    //tabBrowser.TabPages.Add(tab1);
    //tab1.Controls.Add(wb1);
    //wb1.Navigate(e.Uri);
}
```

Comment: Why not "wb1.CreateWindow"?